# Entender código para fins de estudos (OBI - Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Gostaria de entender um algoritmo sobre a OBI 2017 - Cortando Papel link: https://olimpiada.ic.unicamp.br/pratique/pu/2017/f2/papel/ não conseguir entender o motivo pelo qual na hora de fazer os cortes de papel ele usou um módulo de h[1] - start % 2:

```
start = 0 if heights[0] > heights[1] else 1
max_count = 2
count = 1
for h in reversed(sorted_heights):
    if (h[1] - start) % 2 == 0:
        count += 1
    elif h != heights[0][1] and h != heights[-1]:
        count -= 1

    if count > max_count:
        max_count = count
```

Código completo:

```
def simplify(heights):
    new_heights = []
    new_heights.append([heights[0], 0])

    ascending = True if heights[0] < heights[1] else False
    for i in range(1, len(heights)):
        actual_ascending = True if heights[i - 1] < heights[i] else False
        if actual_ascending != ascending:
            new_heights.append([heights[i - 1], new_heights[-1][1] + 1])
            ascending = actual_ascending

    if heights[-2] != heights[-1]:
        print(heights[-2])
        print(heights[-1])
        new_heights.append([heights[-1], new_heights[-1][1] + 1])
    return new_heights

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Número de retângulos
    input()

    # Alturas
    heights = simplify([int(x) for x in input().split()])

    sorted_heights = heights[:]
    sorted_heights.sort()

    start = 0 if heights[0] > heights[1] else 1
    max_count = 2
    count = 1
    for h in reversed(sorted_heights):
        if (h[1] - start) % 2 == 0:
            count += 1
        elif h != heights[0][1] and h != heights[-1]:
            count -= 1

        if count > max_count:
            max_count = count

    print(max_count)
```

Agradeço muito quem poder me ajudar.

Comment: `x % 2 == 0` só será verdadeiro se `x` for par. É isso que você não entendeu?

Comment: Isso eu entendi, o que não entendi é porque tem que ser par, porque ele puxa a posição e não a altura do retângulo, ai no que é par ele soma como se tivesse efetuado um corte, isso que fiquei sem entender, porque tem que ser par para ser verdadeiro e ele efetuar um corte? Pois a conta que tem ali é o corte sendo contado para representar o número máximo de cortes.

Comment: Por que removeu? É boa a pergunta. Eu pretendia estudar o algoritmo pra tentar te responder :)

Comment: Restaurei, eu acabei fazendo uma alteração por não ter entendido essa parte, mas gostaria muito pois em alguma ocasião poderia usar esse raciocínio, eu acredito que pode está "incorreto" e que funcionou por mera coincidência.